# publishing in rospy and subscribing in rosjava

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can my publisher in rospy and subscriber in rosjava be in two separate packages in the same workspace?I am new to ROS and there are different build commands for rospy like catkin_make and gradlew for rosjava. Can i use the same workspace for building both the scripts by putting them in two seperate packages or should i put them in the same package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100516/publishing-in-rospy-and-subscribing-in-rosjava/) by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2013-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They can both be in separate packages in the same work space (that's the usual way to do it anyway).

**Update:** I'm not sure how to get rosjava-based packages to automatically get built using catkin. On rosbuild, simply creating a Makefile in the package directory with the following contents worked:

```
all:
   gradle
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2013-11-15**:
but then how do i build them separately with catkin_make for rospy and gradle for rosjava?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-11-15**:
See update.